# Improvements of Django 1.6

Tags: database, django, django-models, migration, django-south

I know latest release of Django is now 1.6 and there is a list of improvments but i'm just wondering, does Django 1.6 now have it's on 'built in "South" application' which can do schemamigrations and what not without needing South? When I used Django 1.5 I remember I needed to install South to change a model once it has already been synced using syncdb. Do I still need South to do this with Django 1.6?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Migrations will be part of Django 1.7](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.7/#schema-migrations). In Django 1.6 and earlier, you need to install south.

Comment: hm okay thanks. But oh man, any idea when Django 1.7 will be released as a stable non development version? Probably not soon right since Django 1.6 released recently?

Comment: There was a nine month gap between Django 1.5 and 1.6. If there is a similar gap between 1.6 and 1.7, then it won't be released for a while.